# Entity Framework 6 stored procedure returns only one item (record)

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I’ve the following stored procedure (returns the number of events from a machine per hour):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ReceivedEventsPerTimePerMachine 
    @dateFrom datetime,  
    @dateTo datetime, 
    @machineId uniqueidentifier
AS
    IF DATEPART(MINUTE, @dateFrom) != 0 OR DATEPART(SECOND,@dateFrom)!= 0 OR DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@dateFrom)!= 0
        RAISERROR ('dateFrom exceeds maximum precision. Only full hours are allowed.', 16, 1)
    IF DATEPART(MINUTE, @dateTo) != 0 OR DATEPART(SECOND,@dateTo)!= 0 OR DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@dateTo)!= 0
        RAISERROR ('dateTo exceeds maximum precision. Only full hours are allowed.', 16, 1)

    IF (@@ERROR = 0) 
        SELECT  
            DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, ReceiveDateTime), DATEADD(day, day(ReceiveDateTime) - 1, DATEADD(month, month(ReceiveDateTime) - 1, DATEADD(Year, year(ReceiveDateTime) - 1900, 0)))) AS DateTime, 
            COUNT(*) AS [NumberOfEvents] 
        FROM 
            ReceivedEvents 
        WHERE 
            ReceiveDateTime BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo 
            AND MachineId = @machineId
        GROUP BY  
            DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, ReceiveDateTime), DATEADD(day, day(ReceiveDateTime) - 1, DATEADD(month, month(ReceiveDateTime) - 1, DATEADD(Year, year(ReceiveDateTime) - 1900, 0))))
        ORDER BY 
            DateTime
```

I execute the procedure using EF6, this is my C# code:

```
var result = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<EventsPerDateTime>( "sp_ReceivedEventsPerTimePerMachine @dateFrom, @dateTo, @machineId",
    new SqlParameter( "dateFrom", fromDateTime ), new SqlParameter( "dateTo", toDateTime ), new SqlParameter( "machineId", machine.MachineId ) )
        .ToListAsync();
```

Executing the procedure using EF always returns only one record, but the procedure returns multiple values. Executing the procedure directly (using SQL Management Studio) return more than one record.

How can I get all records returned by the select statement using EF?

**EDIT:**

Here is my full code

Here is the `EventsPerDateTime` class:

```
public class EventsPerDateTime
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Int32 NumberOfEvents { get; set; }
}
```

The service used to abstract EF

```
public class SqlService<TContext> : Disposable, ISqlService<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private TContext _context;
    private TContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _context == null )
            {
                Logger.Debug( "Request DbContext form database factory." );
                _context = DatabaseFactory.GetDb();
            }
            return _context;
        }
    }

    public IDatabaseFactory<TContext> DatabaseFactory { get; }

    public SqlService( IDatabaseFactory<TContext> databaseFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
        : base( loggerFactory.CreateLogger( typeof (SqlService<TContext>) ) )
    {
        Logger.Trace( "Enter Ctor - Exit on next line." );
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    }

    protected override void Disposed()
    {
        if ( _context != null )
            _context.Dispose();
    }

    public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>( String sql, params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return Context.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>( sql, parameters );
    }

    public DbRawSqlQuery SqlQuery( Type elementType, String sql, params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return Context.Database.SqlQuery( elementType, sql, parameters );
    }

    public Int32 ExecuteSqlCommand( String sql, params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( sql, parameters );
    }

    public Int32 ExecuteSqlCommand( TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( transactionalBehavior, sql, parameters );
    }

    public async Task<Int32> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( String sql, params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( sql, parameters );
    }

    public async Task<Int32> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior,
                                                     String sql,
                                                     params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( transactionalBehavior, sql, parameters );
    }

    public async Task<Int32> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( String sql,
                                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                                     params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( sql, cancellationToken, parameters );
    }

    public async Task<Int32> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior,
                                                     String sql,
                                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                                     params Object[] parameters )
    {
        return await Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync( transactionalBehavior, sql, cancellationToken, parameters );
    }
```

The call to the service

```
var toDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours( DateTime.Now.Hour );
var fromDateTime = toDateTime.Subtract( Parameters.ReceivedEventsOfLastHours.ToHours() );
var result =
    await SqlService.SqlQuery<EventsPerDateTime>( "sp_ReceivedEventsPerTimePerMachine @dateFrom, @dateTo, @machineId",
                                                  new SqlParameter( "dateFrom", fromDateTime ),
                                                  new SqlParameter( "dateTo", toDateTime ),
                                                  new SqlParameter( "machineId", machine.MachineId ) )
                    .ToListAsync();
```

The generated SQL (captured using SQL Server Profiler):

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'sp_ReceivedEventsPerTimePerMachine @dateFrom, @dateTo, @machineId',
N'@dateFrom datetime,@dateTo datetime,@machineId uniqueidentifier',
@dateFrom='2015-10-19 22:00:00',@dateTo='2015-10-21 22:00:00',@machineId='B0BDD062-0178-E511-9BD8-801F02F47041'
```

Comment: What is the item it returns? Is it actual data from the database? Are you suing this SP in an async function? If so are you awaiting it? The .ToListAsync() needs to await

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676563/entity-framework-queryable-async for more information on this.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll The SP returns a set of records (actual data from the DB) with two columns (DateTime: datetime and NumberOfEvents: int). Sorry, I await the execution in my productive code (I’ve simplified the code a little because I use a service to abstract the call to EF)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual code you're using? It will make it easier to identify the issue. As it is now, it doesn't appear that you're doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I’ve added the full code (I tried to make the question easier by not adding my full code)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Haha my DBA told me to use this prefix… this will be a funny conversation tomorrow morning^^ Thank you!

Comment: Nothing is sticking out as an issue. What is Parameters.ReceivedEventsOfLastHours.ToHours()? Could this possibly be giving you an unexpected value causing your date range to be incorrect?

Comment: no ToHours returns a valid datetime object

Comment: Have you watched the value and make sure it's not returning the same DateTime as fromDateTime or something? This would cause your date range to include only records that have been received/submitted this hour only. This is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: No the values are correct. The values are to: {21/10/2015 22:00:00} from: {19/10/2015 22:00:00}

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I’ve added the actual SQL script (from EF) to the question. Executing exactly this scripts (using SQL Server ManagementStudio) returns two records: {2015-10-21 16:00:00.000, 12} {2015-10-21 17:00:00.000, 18}. Calling the SP from C#/EF returns only the first record (with NumberOfEvents  = 12)