# How to get all object from Async

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The follow code only returns one object, the first one.

```
var person = await personService.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Emails.Any(e => e.EmailAddress == email));
```

This was my previous one without async

```
var peopleWithEmail = People.Where(p => p.Emails.Any(e => e.Email == email));
```

There isn't an WhereAsync... I might also have no idea what I'm talking or doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Queryable async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676563/entity-framework-queryable-async)

Comment: Use `await People.Where(p => p.Emails.Any(e => e.Email == email)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: thx, tolistasync worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get object using `async` method:

```
await People.Where(p => p.Emails.Any(e => e.Email == email)).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
await People.Where(p => p.Emails.Email==email).ToListAsync();
```