How can I have an async response with an IQueryable?
I get the warning message
This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
The code that produces this warning is
app.MapGet("/questionsByCategory", async (Context dbContext, int categoryId, bool inTest) =>
        {
            IQueryable<Questions> result = dbContext.Questions
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
                .Include(x => x.Answers)
                .AsQueryable();

            if (inTest)
                result.Where(x => x.InTest == true);

            return Results.Ok(result);
        })
        .WithName("questionsByCategory")
        .WithOpenApi();


I think it has been explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26677047/9855767

Updated according to Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment:
Add the .ToListAsync() call before returning the result.
Here's an updated code snippet:
app.MapGet("/questionsByCategory", async (Context dbContext, int categoryId, bool inTest) =>
        {
            IQueryable<Questions> query = dbContext.Questions
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
                .Include(x => x.Answers)
                .AsQueryable();

            if (inTest)
                query.Where(x => x.InTest == true);

            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            return Results.Ok(result);
        })
        .WithName("questionsByCategory")
        .WithOpenApi();


It looks like they're trying to chain on an optional Where condition which ideally would be processed by the queryable too, usually, so the ToListAsync() should probably be in the return line instead.
